# "error": "Internal Api Error: Invalid object name 'starter_core.Users'."

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, postman, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I've deployed a ASP.NET Core project for managing Identity system in IIS, and i am trying to test the authentification API that works correctly without IIS, This is the database that i have :
[image: Tables]

now with IIS a problem is showing with this Error in postman :

```js
{
    "error": "Internal Api Error: Invalid object name 'starter_core.Users'."
}
```

[image: Postman]

Comment: Please provide method that is responsible for authentication

Comment: `var result = await authService.Login(loginDto);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok(new { token = result.Data });
            }
            if (result.IsModelValid)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return BadRequest();`

Comment: Looks like error is in the `authService.Login`. Please provide it too.

Comment: it's from the implementation of interface `Task<AuthResult<Token>> Login(LoginDTO loginDto);`

Comment: And in service ` if (loginDto == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginDto.Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginDto.Password))
                return AuthResult<Token>.UnvalidatedResult;

            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginDto.Email);

            if (user != null && user.Id > 0)
            {
                if (await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginDto.Password))
                {
                    var token = jwtManager.GenerateToken(user);
                    return..;
                }
            }

            return ..`

Comment: Are you using the same database that you used for testing?

Comment: Yes the same database

Comment: Looks like your app can't find that table. Check that it has expected name, and if you changed something try updating the model/database

Comment: Firstly I suggest you could make sure the IIS and localdb database is on the same machine. Besides, I suggest you could post details information about  test the authentification API that works correctly without IIS. Do you mean you run the core application directly by using command line. Could you please post the command you have used?

Comment: I test my API correctly without IIS using the local execution of vs and postman.. , when i deploy my app in IIS the API doesn't work and it shows the error i post

Comment: I even updated the schema of table to dbo the error now is "error": "Internal Api Error: Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'."

Comment: Is the IIS and your visual studio on the same server? I mean you should firstky make sure your IIS web server could access the localdb firstly. Then the IIS will use the application pool account to access the localdb, this is not as same as visual studio.